# Plug in for turn.js in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to insert my webpage in wordpress. I created my webpage in turn.js using javascript, CSS, HTML & jquery. The turn.js link is stored in my local. But i want to know how to store the turn.js link in wordpress.

I want to upload my flipbook using Turn.js in my wordpress blog. It is working fine in local. What is the plugin to install in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a template file not js file. then you can create new page and assign this template to that page.Also you have to upload all necessary js and css file to the your WordPress blog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your local site into a WordPress Theme, and include the turn.js library. You can get information Theme Development from [WordPress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), or by doing a google search and referencing one of the many articles on the subject.